# Fastest way to retrieve single value from EntityCollection

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have an Entitycollection that I am converting into a List as follows:

```C#
var List = Lines.Entities.Where(p =>
                    p.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_time").Value == 100000003).Select(e =>
                    new {

                        group = e.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_group"),
                        desc = e.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_desc"),
                        numbers = new Dictionary<string, int>()
                            {
                                {"monday", e.GetAttributeValue<int>("new_mondayunits") },
                                {"tuesday", e.GetAttributeValue<int>("new_tuesdayunits") },
                                {"wednesday", e.GetAttributeValue<int>("new_wednesdayunits")},
                                {"thursday", e.GetAttributeValue<int>("new_thursdayunits") },
                                {"friday", e.GetAttributeValue<int>("new_fridayunits") }
                            }

                    }).ToList();
```

I retrieve the value on the day that I want like this :

```c#
var value = List.Where(e => e.group == group && e.desc == desc).Select(e => e.numbers["monday"]);
```

My intention is to retrieve values from EntityCollection in the fastest way possible as the values are called from within a for loop. I'm not sure if converting the entitycollection to a list helps. Here is the entitycollection:

```c#
                    string fetchContractLines = @"  
                        <fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical'>
                            <entity name='new_contractline'>
                                <attribute name='new_group' />
                                <attribute name='new_desc' />
                                <attribute name='new_time' />
                                <attribute name='new_mondayunits' />
                                <attribute name='new_tuesdayunits' />
                                <attribute name='new_wednesdayunits' />
                                <attribute name='new_thursdayunits' />
                                <attribute name='new_fridayunits' />
                                <filter type='and'>
                                    <condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='0' />
                                    <condition attribute='new_contractid' operator='eq' value='{" + contractId.ToString() + @"}' />
                                    <condition attribute='new_group' operator='not-null' />
                                    <condition attribute='new_time' operator='not-null' />
                                    <condition attribute='new_desc' operator='not-null' />
                                </filter>
                            </entity>
                        </fetch>";


                    EntityCollection Lines = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchContractLines));
```

The reason I need speed is that I am hitting the 2-minute limit on plugin execution and thought I could reduce the amount of time it take by reducing the lookup time.

Comment: Does `FirstOrDefault()` do what you want?

Comment: Are you expecting one line per Group / Description pair `.Where(e => e.group == group && e.desc == desc)`?  If so, `.Single()` will return one and only one line, and throw an exception if more or less than one exist.

Comment: @Aron depending on your use-case `single` is a lot slower than `first` or `firstordefault` because it iterates through the entire collection to ensure that this is a "single" match, whereas `first` and `firstordefault` will exit the collection as soon as a match is found

Comment: Yes, I need the fastest way possible!! The question is essentially what's the fastest way of getting a single integer value from that collection! I am expecting only a single value, however, if it doesn't exist then I want a zero in place of that value!

Comment: Thanks @jasonscript fro the heads up. Makes sense. Looks like `FirstOrDefault()` fits the bill perfectly.

Comment: Yes, but is it necessary to convert to list then pull the value from the list? Is there a better and faster way by taking it directly from the entitycollection?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a dictionary instead, but still unsure if there is a faster way to retrieve the value from the collection:

```c#
var Lookup = Lines.Entities.Where(e => e.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_time").Value == 100000001).Select(r => new
                    {
                        group = r.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_group").Value,
                        desc = r.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_desc"),
                        numbers = new Dictionary<string, int>()
                        {
                            {"monday", r.GetAttributeValue<int>("new_mondayunits") },
                            {"tuesday", r.GetAttributeValue<int>("new_tuesdayunits") },
                            {"wednesday", r.GetAttributeValue<int>("new_wednesdayunits") },
                            {"thursday", r.GetAttributeValue<int>("new_thursdayunits") },
                            {"friday", r.GetAttributeValue<int>("new_fridayunits") }
                        }
                    }).ToDictionary(t => t.group.ToString() + t.desc, t => t.numbers);
```

```
var quan = Lookup.ContainsKey(key) ? amLookup[key][currentday] : 0;
```